# Photodiode bias in TIA?

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, transimpedance

When I see TIA schematics, I can see either the photodiode to GND or against VCC. What is the difference?

[image]

Comment: Both of your circuits produce zero bias across the photodiode. If you want reverse bias in the second diagram, set the non-inverting input to GND, and deal with the fact that the output voltage will be below ground.

Comment: Or use the first diagram, but apply a negative voltage to the PD anode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: photodiode is a **current source**, which suggests its internal resistance is mighty high...often hundreds of Megohms for a small-area diode.

Zero-bias (GND):

- minimum leakage current and temperature-induced currents added to photo-current
- minimum noise
- highest capacitance, slowing response time.

---

High-reverse-bias voltage source (Vcc):

- less diode capacitance, for fast response time.
- leakage current is higher, causing DC offset.

---

In some circuits, the photodiode is placed between op-amp "-" and "+" inputs - this is equivalent to zero-bias operation.

Comment: Also it seems the high-reverse-bias, would need a Vref on V-, not on the other case right?

Comment: Linearity is also greatly increased by using bias.

Comment: Any bias supply *must* reverse-bias the diode. The resulting leakage currents are in the same direction as photo-current. So if anode attaches to bias-supply, the supply must be more negative - a cathode attached to bias-supply would require V+.

Comment: Reverse bias also widens the depletion zone, which improves the quantum efficiency, especially in the infrared.